# Why does VBA fail to sort this range?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following range (obviously not mine, but MWE):

[image: excel range description]

And I am looking to sort it using VBA. here is my code:

```
Sub test()
    LR = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Rows.Count + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows(1).Row - 1

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim sort_range As Range

    Set ws = ActiveWorksheet.Worksheets(1)
    Set sort_range = ws.Range("C$2$:$E$" & LR)

    Call sort_range.Sort(Key1:=sl_ws.Range("$C$2"), Order1:=xlAscending, _
                            Key2:=sl_ws.Range("$D$2"), Order2:=xlAscending, _
                            Key3:=sl_ws.Range("$E$2"), Order3:=xlAscending, _
                            Header:=xlYes)
End Sub
```

This returns that the following error:

[image: error],

directing me to this line:

```
    Set sort_range = ws.Range("C$2$:$E$" & LR)
```

What am I doing wrong? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Range("C$2$:$E$" & LR)` - you have the dollar signs in wrong places - should be `Range("$C$2:$E$" & LR)`.

Comment: Great catch! Thanks much.